# Understanding JavaScript's pass-by-value

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

As we know, everything is pass-by-value in JavaScript, even the *Objects* as function parameters are treated like a pass-by-value of the actual reference to the object.

My question is how is that possible that I have access to an Object like I can modify a property of it -- talking about objects passed to the functions as parameters, but I can *not* rewrite the Object itself?

Is that an intentional mechanism to avoid some errors or it's just a design-flaw or a limit? If it's intentional what is trying to achieve with that? What is the added benefit and what type of bugs/errors could happen with the ability to rewrite the object itself?

I totally understand that it is caused by pass-by-value of the object reference, however I can't figure out what is stopping me from rewriting the Object that I already have a copy of its reference -- and I can modify it as well.

Example:

```
var x = { arr: [1,2,3] };

var modify = function ( _x ) {
    _x.arr.push(4);
}

var rewrite = function ( _x ) {
    _x = { str: "X" };
    // OR
    _x = "X";
}

modify(x);
console.log( "X after modification: ", x );
rewrite(x);
console.log( "X after rewrite: ", x );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5TEy/)

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite" an object? That's what something like `x.foo = "X"` would do. `x = "X"` rewrites the reference, not the object. If you want to do something like stomp over the object's memory area and turn it into a string instead, there's not enough benefit to such a feature to justify the bugs it would cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while inside the modify or rewrite methods variables x and _x are references to the same object.  The rewrite function changes the _x variable to point to another object.  This does not change the x variable's reference which still points to the original object.

Comment: Thanks for the input; But do you know why is that pointing out to another memory address? Are basically telling me that it will create a new _Object_ instead of actually rewriting the referenced one?

Comment: right- this line: `_x = { str: "X" };` creates a new object and updates the `_x` variable to point at it.  The `x` variable still points at the original object.

Comment: Great! Now I see how it works! One more thing: Do you think that is caused by changing the _context_ from where x has been created to the scope of the function? So it will result in creating a new object instead of replacing the previous one or there is another reason for that?

Comment: `x` and `_x` are separate variables.  Upon entry into the `rewrite` function both `x` and `_x` point to the same object on the heap:  `{ arr: [1,2,3] }`.  After this line `_x = { str: "X" };`, `_x` points to a different object on the heap:  `{ str: "X" }`.  `x` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite a reference with a different value or you can change a property of the object that is referenced.

JavaScript has no mechanism to change where a reference points to. The syntax just doesn't exist, and that is why you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is any advantage of doing so? Does that prevent me from doing some stupid thing or the syntax just doesn't exist?

Comment: It's possible to to stupid things with almost anything in any programming language. I'm not eager to speculate on the language designer's reasons for writing JS that way.